# Getting today's date from a specific date format in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to get today's date with the format below in React:

```
    "2019020420"
```

I am able to get the current date with this function. How do I modify this such that it will give me the above date format?

```
     getCurrentDate() {    
            var tempDate = new Date();
            var date = tempDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (tempDate.getMonth()+1) + '-' + tempDate.getDate() +' '+ tempDate.getHours()+':'+ tempDate.getMinutes()+':'+ tempDate.getSeconds();
            const currDate = date;
            return currDate;       
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Which format is that?

Comment: Doesnt specifically answer your question but i would highly recommend using something like moment.js if you're working with dates in js

Comment: This format. 2019020420

Comment: can you please specify exactly what is your date format? e.g. YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
let formatTwoDigits = (digit) => ("0" + digit).slice(-2);
var tempDate = new Date();
var date = `${tempDate.getFullYear()}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getMonth()+1)}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getDate())}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getHours())}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getMinutes())}${formatTwoDigits(tempDate.getSeconds())}`;
console.log(date);
```

However, implementing date formatting by ourselves sometimes could be tedious. If you don't mind using a library, you can take a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and its [format functions](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). Moment.js is a commonly used JS library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting dates.

Answer (score 0):

try this library for formatting date in your desired format.
 https://date-fns.org/

Answer (score 0):

use moment.js from https://momentjs.com/
Take a look at there first few examples for how to use it for reformatting dates.